# How to make two equations dimensionless?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, dimensional-analysis, flow

I recently got set this problem and am having trouble scaling the resulting equations. Any help would be appreciated.

An incompressible thermal conducting fluid is contained between two infinite horizontal plates separated by a distance $H$. Initially the plates and fluid are at rest at temperature $T_0$. At time $t = 0$ the upper plate is raised to temperature $T_1 > T_0$ and moved horizontally at speed $U$. Assume the fluid flow is laminar.

I now need to scale the following two equations that I have derived:
$ \rho u_t(y,t)=\mu u_{yy}(y,t)$ and $\rho cT_t(y,t)=kT_{yy}(y,t) + \mu (u_y(y,t))^2$.

I decide to let $y=Ly'$, $u=Uu'$, $t=t_{0}t'$ and $T=T_{0}+(T_{1}-T_{0})T'$ but I am having trouble with the scaling.

I ended up with $u'_{t'}=\frac{\mu t_{0}}{L^2 \rho}u'_{y'y'}$ and $T'_{t'}=\frac{kt_{0}}{\rho c L^2}T'_{y'y'} + \frac{\mu U^2 t_{0}}{L^2 \rho c (T_{1}-T_{0})}u'_{y'}$, but I'm not convinced this is correct. Apologies for the long question.

Comment: your result looks correct. Since the characteristic length and velocity scales are given respectively as $L$ and $U$, what is left is to determine the characteristic time scale $t_0$. Do this by requiring that the all terms in your equation should be $O(1)$ or smaller. Based on your equation there are three possibilities for $t_0$. I will give you the most obvious: $t_0=L^2/\nu$ where $\nu=\mu/\rho$

Comment: also you say 'Apologies for the long question' but there is no question mark anywhere in your post. Improve your post by actually asking a question and it might be reopened. Make sure to ask something more specific than: "is this correct?" because per my comment above the answer to that is "yes".

Comment: Yes, I understand that $t_{0}=\frac{L^2 \rho}{\mu}$ which then gives $T'_{t'}=\frac{k}{c\mu}T'_{y'y'} + \frac{U^2}{c(T_{1}-T_{0})}(u'_{y'})^2$, but then what can you do? As all the constants remaining are pre-determined, which means they cannot be changed? Thanks for all your help by the way!

Comment: The coefficients in front of the terms on the rhs now form two dimensionless numbers which characterize the system. The first is viscous vs thermal diffusion (Prandtl number) and the second is the relative importance of viscous dissipation vs molecular transport (Brinkman number). The Brinkman number is found by multiplying the last term by the Prandtl number. If your choice of the viscous time scale is the characteristic time scale of the system, then all terms in the equation should be $O(1)$ or smaller. If they are not, you need to rescale with a different time scale.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot! So those are the two dimensionless groups right?